# Split a file path into folder names vector

Tags: r

In R, with `file.path`, you can convert a character vector into a full file path, automatically using the correct file separator for your platform :

```
> file.path("home", "foo", "script.R")
[1] "home/foo/script.R"
```

I'd like to do exactly the reverse : split a file path into a character vector of components. So far I almost manage to do it with a recursive function, but I don't find it very elegant :

```
split_path <- function(file) {
  if(!(file %in% c("/", "."))) {
    res <- c(basename(file), split_path(dirname(file)))
    return(res)
  }
  else return(NULL)
}
```

Which gives :

```
> split_path("/home/foo/stats/index.html")
[1] "index.html" "stats"      "foo"        "home"
```

Do you know of any already existing function, or at least a better way to do such a thing ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :** I think I'll finally stick to this slightly different recursive version, thanks to @James, which should handle drive letters and network shares under Windows :

```
split_path <- function(path) {
  if (dirname(path) %in% c(".", path)) return(basename(path))
  return(c(basename(path), split_path(dirname(path))))
}
```

Comment: Is `strsplit` not good enough?

Comment: Also try `.Platform$file.sep` if you want platform independence; see the code for `file.path`.

Comment: @Dason, well, I thought that `dirname()` may do a bit more than `strsplit()`, such as dealing with escaped file separators, these sort of things.

Comment: At least that's what it seems when looking at `dirname()` [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/354e3abe9574f4f830cb983bd1f6720e6e05e852/src/main/util.c#L862).

Comment: Can you provide more sample input and expected output

Comment: Trying your function one something like "~/Github/test.csv" gives an error.  From what you were saying I would have thought that tilde expansion would have been one of the things handled but it seems to be a case where it fails.

Comment: @Dason what os are you using ? It seems to work here under Linux.

Comment: And ~ expansion seems to work under Windows, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it with a simple recursive function, by terminating when the `dirname` doesn't change:

```
split_path <- function(x) if (dirname(x)==x) x else c(basename(x),split_path(dirname(x)))
split_path("/home/foo/stats/index.html")
[1] "index.html" "stats"      "foo"        "home"       "/" 
split_path("C:\\Windows\\System32")
[1] "System32" "Windows"  "C:/"
split_path("~")
[1] "James"  "Users" "C:/"
```

Comment: Yes, that's better. I'll use a slightly modified version, see the edit part in my question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I've seen a recursive function in R.  I had no idea you could this (I would have expected an error)

Answer (score 9):

Try this (will work with both "/" and "\"):

```
split_path <- function(path) {
    rev(setdiff(strsplit(path,"/|\\\\")[[1]], ""))
}
```

**Results**

```
split_path("/home/foo/stats/index.html")
# [1] "index.html" "stats"      "foo"        "home"

rev(split_path("/home/foo/stats/index.html"))
# [1] "home"       "foo"        "stats"      "index.html"
```

**Edit**

Making use of `normalizePath`, `dirname` and `basename`, this version will give different results:

```
split_path <- function(path, mustWork = FALSE, rev = FALSE) {
    output <- c(strsplit(dirname(normalizePath(path,mustWork = mustWork)),
                                             "/|\\\\")[[1]], basename(path))
    ifelse(rev, return(rev(output)), return(output))
}

split_path("/home/foo/stats/index.html", rev=TRUE)
# [1] "index.html" "stats"      "foo"        "home"       "D:"
```

Comment: Thanks, that could do it, maybe using `.Platform$file.Sep` instead of your regular expression. But I believe that `dirname` may do a bit more than that, such as path expansion under OSX/Linux, dealing with drive letters and network shares under Windows, etc.

Comment: For .Platform$file.Sep, it is a single string; since R accepts both / and \\ (at least on Windows and Linux), the regex simply takes into account both possibilities. For the `dirname`, it could be integrated it to the function. I'll make an edit.

Comment: There is one problem with using `normalizePath`, because it converts relative paths to absolute paths. But your function is quite good, I'll accept it even if I may stick with my ugly recursive one. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5):

you can use the package `DescTools` to solve the problem:

```r
library(DescTools)

SplitPath('C:/users/losses/development/R/loveResearch/src/signalPreprocess.R')
```

The output is:

```r
$normpath
[1] "C:\\users\\losses\\development\\R\\loveResearch\\src\\signalPreprocess.R"

$drive
[1] "C:"

$dirname
[1] "/users/losses/development/R/loveResearch/src/"

$fullfilename
[1] "signalPreprocess.R"

$filename
[1] "signalPreprocess"

$extension
[1] "R"
```

Pretty convenient.