# Stop substr at path separator?

Tags: r, csv, subset, substr

I want to name a file according to specific section of the file path.
Is it possible to have a substr stop at a path separator?

For example, I want an output file to read "worldclim.csv"

if I am extracting data from this path:"F:\Data\WorldClim\masked\Africa"
I want the output file to be named: "worldclim.csv"

Here is an example:

```
(file.out <- runif(4))
(path <- "F:\\Data\\WorldClim\\masked\\Africa")
(pname <- sapply(path, function(x) substr(x,start=9,stop=17)))
write.csv(file.out, paste0("F:\\Data\\extractions\\", pname, ".csv"), row.names=F)
```

However, I need to do this for many directories, and the sub-directories inside "Data" have different character lengths.

In short, I want "file.out" to be named after the directory that follows Data. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Do all the directories have a consistent depth? Could you use a combination of `basename` and `dirname`?

Comment: Yea, all the data I extract are in various subdirectories inside of 'Data', but the folder names have different character length.

Comment: Maybe, let me look into basename.

Comment: In general, you should always be using `file.path` to specify paths.

Comment: To elaborate a little more: Path formatting differs by OS, and `file.path` takes care of the differences for you. For example, the string you gave is not recognized as a path for Mac users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can simply split on `\\`:

```
strsplit(path, '\\\\')[[1]][3]
# [1] "WorldClim"

# or

strsplit(path, '\\', fixed = TRUE)[[1]][3]
# [1] "WorldClim"
```

or use `regex` to match 8 characters from start and then extract the pattern until the next `\\`:

```
sub('^.{8}([^\\]+).*$', '\\1', path)
# [1] "WorldClim"
```

Comment: (+1) This is much more computationally efficient (and more specifically answers the question of how to do the string matching), but will break down when porting the code to different OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate `dirname` and `basename`:

```
path <- file.path("F:", "Data", "WorldClim", "masked", "Africa")
basename(dirname(dirname((path))))
# [1] "WorldClim"
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29232017/1623354) provides a nice function for splitting paths. You could then subset on the index of whatever folder you'd like. I have wrapped it in an additional function (because the original function is recursive), to the output in the correct order.

```
split_path <- function(x) {
  if (dirname(x) == x) x else c(basename(x), split_path(dirname(x)))
}
splitPath <- function(x) rev(split_path(x))
splitPath(path)[4]
# [1] "WorldClim"
```

Comment: I did not know about file.path. I always keep one path commented 'windows', and one path commented 'mac' to switch back and forth... hahaha

Comment: @SoilSciGuy Check out the edit with the new function. The solution provided will be robust across operating systems, as it does not require finding an OS-specific separator.

Comment: Nice! One thing, I needed to subset with [3] to return 'WorldClim' using your code..