# How to split a file path platform independently in R

Tags: r, split, cross-platform, filepath

I want to split a path into its components and want this to work on all platforms.

I know the title looks like a question that lacks prior research, so I documented the results of the google queries I did below.

I thought this was easy with

```
strsplit("C:\\Path to\\file", .Platform$file.sep)
```

, however, the documentation `?.Platform` says:

> ...[this is] "/" on both Unix-alikes *and* on Windows ...

What works for the common cases I can think of is

```
strsplit("C:\\Path to\\file", "[\\/]")
```

but I can already think of one non-working corner case: UNC paths (`\\server\folder\file`) and maybe there are more on other platforms?

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29232017/3082472) using repeated calls to `dirname` and `basename` until there is no change of the result anymore. This handles UNC paths better but not ideal (it adds a `"."` as last element). This seems to be the most promising candidate I've come across so far.

## Questions

1. What is the use of `.Platform$file.sep` when it does not include the Windows separator "\"?
2. What is the canonical way of splitting a path into its components platform-independently on R?

---

**Appendix: Search queries:**

I did a google search for "r file path split platform independent -python" (because I only got python results), but the results indicate no solution:

> - R: Construct Path to File *(`?file.path` help page)
> - Split text file by line, platform-independently - Stack Overflow (java)
> - Difference between File.separator and slash in paths - Stack Overflow
> - 2 Efficient set-up - Efficient R programming (https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/set-up.htm)
> - (more results concerning MATLAB, Node.js, Perl,...)

Results when only searching Stack Overflow:

> - java - Split text file by line, platform-independently
> - java - File.separator and slash in paths
> - r - File.separator. Saving file path imported by file.choose () in R
> - r - Saving file path imported by file.choose () in R
> - javascript - JavaScript Platform Independent Line separator
> - java - Java String.Split while printwriting - Stack Overflow
> - vb.net - Valid filename check. What is the best way?
> - r - What is a way to manage paths to local files outside a git repository...
> - c# - How can I split a textfile by three empty lines?
> - perl - NewLine as a platform independent new line. How to split and concatenate strings in Perl?

Comment: Because .Platform$file.sep refers to how R interprets flie path separation. Maybe ?normalizePath is more what you are looking for

Comment: @WD11 what do you mean with "how R interprets file path separation"? The help page says ".Platform is a list with some details of the platform under which R was built. This provides means to write OS-portable R code.", so shouldn't I expect values which refer to how my platform interprets things and not how R interprets things? Your idea using normalizePath sounds promising, however it only works for existing files.

Comment: @akraf `normalizePath` works also for non existing files (it just gives a warning, which you can get rid of with `suppressWarnings`). R, also on windows, uses the `/` as file separator: `list.files` and similar functions all returns path using `/`.