# What would be the equivalent to str.split("/path/to/file", os.sep) from Python in R

Tags: python, r, split, operating-system

I thought there would be something similar in R to split up a filepath by the operating system separator, but couldn't find anything super useful.

Comment: As a minor comment, in Python what you would actually use is `os.path.split`.

Comment: ah great, thanks. Didn't know that:) I just wondered if there is any variable defined in `R` that like `os.sep` in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `strsplit`

```r
strsplit("/path/to/file", .Platform$file.sep)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Python but from your description this is most likely what you are looking for:

```
.Platform$file.sep
```

returns "/" on my comuter as default file separator. You can further use `basename()` and `dirname()` to split a path into it's components.

See also this question: [Split a file path into folder names vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214932/split-a-file-path-into-folder-names-vector)